# Minimum edge cover of the Petersen graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, examples-counterexamples

I want to find a minimum edge-cover of the Petersen graph.

It is my understand that an edge cover is a set of vertices which is connected to all edges in the graph. Is this correct? I'm struggling to visualize what this would look like.

[image]

Comment: An edge cover is a set of **edges** of the graph so that given **any vertex**, there is **some edge** in your cover so that the given vertex is an endpoint of the edge. In you example, that would translate to something like the set : $ae,dc,bg,fi,jh$ for example.

Comment: Furthermore, this paper contains some results that may interest you, since you like to work with Petersen graphs: http://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/40/ajc_v40_p253.pdf